# Check if UIWebView is done loading in Swift

Tags: swift, swift3, uiwebview, webkit

I am making an application that loads a UIWeb View and runs a line of code the moment the webpage is completely loaded.

I am using code like this to load the webpage:

```
    let links = URL (string: "https://example.com")
    let loadpage = URLRequest(url: links!)
    webPage.loadRequest(load)
```

How can I run a piece of code the moment the webpage is done? I have tried some examples online but the webpage stops loading while checking if it has loaded?

Thanks!

Comment: I have to use UIWebView because of previous coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the documentation of `UIWebView`, for apps targeting iOS8 or later you should be using `WKWebView` instead.

When using a `WKWebView`, you can make your class conform to `WKNavigationDelegate` and the delegate method `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)` will be called once the webview finishes loading a network request.

If for some reason you are still targeting iOS7 or any previous iOS versions and hence the use of a `UIWebView`, you can use `UIWebViewDelegate`'s `func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)` method instead.

Skeleton code for the `UIWebView` solution:

```
class WebVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        webView.delegate = self
        let url = URL(string: "https://example.com")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.loadRequest(request)
    }
}

extension WebVC: UIWebViewDelegate {
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        print("Finished loading")
    }
}
```

Comment: Due to how the app was previously made, it already has a lot of code using UI Web View. Is there any way to do this with UIWebView. Thanks!

Comment: @Bob check the last paragraph of my answer

Comment: I tried running: func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webPage: UIWebView) {
        print("This is done loading")
        
    } This was never printed in the console. Why is this?

Comment: @Bob as I've already stated in my answer, you need to make the class in which the `UIWebView` resides conform to `UIWebViewDelegate` and set the delegate to self.

Comment: @Bob no, that's not what I mean. Check my updated answer for setting up a delegate.